# Running Knex Migrations Between Mocha Tests

Tags: phantomjs, mocha.js, casperjs, knex.js, mocha-phantomjs

I was using Mocha to test my Nodejs app with a test database. In order to reset the DB before each test I had the following code, which worked perfectly:

```
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
  var knex = require('../db/knex');

  describe("Add Item", function() {

      beforeEach(function(done) {
        knex.migrate.rollback()
        .then(function() {
          knex.migrate.latest()
          .then(function() {
            return knex.seed.run()
            .then(function() {
              done();
            });
          });
        });
      });

  ...
```

I've since switched from mocha to mocha-casperjs for my integration tests, and now the knex migrations won't run. I'm given this error message with the exact same before each hook:

```
     undefined is not an object (evaluating 'knex.migrate.rollback')
     phantomjs://platform/new-item.js:12:17
     value@phantomjs://platform/mocha-casperjs.js:114:20
     callFnAsync@phantomjs://platform/mocha.js:4314:12
     run@phantomjs://platform/mocha.js:4266:18
     next@phantomjs://platform/mocha.js:4630:13
     phantomjs://platform/mocha.js:4652:9
     timeslice@phantomjs://platform/mocha.js:12620:27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that migration functionality is not included in webpack build. If you go to http://knexjs.org/ open up debug console and checkout different clients e.g. `mysql.migrate` you see that there are no functions declared at all.

Actually you can check it out with node too if you explicitly load webpack build instead of node lib.

```js
// load webpack build instead of node build...
let knex = require('knex/build/knex')({client : 'pg'});
console.log(knex.migrate);
// outputs: {}
```

So... the question is why are you trying to run your tests on PhantomJS browser instead of node.js?

[image: client.migrate is empty]

Comment: Thanks. Guess I'll avoid Phantomjs for tests that require knex.